# Firebase warns about slow response time for settings.crashlytics.com requests

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Firebase warns me that 10% of the requests to `settings.crashlytics.com` for the settings json took more than 2 seconds.

[image]

When looking over the OS level I can clearly see the lower the version is the slower the request.

[image]

The question is, how can I improve that?
Aren't these settings manages solely by Crashlytics library?

Comment: Its actually firebase warning you isn't it?

Comment: @Ostkontentitan you are right. I've edited the question. Thanks

Comment: I too have the same issue, any solutions on this? 20% of the requests took about 2s is not acceptable

Comment: I also see the same problem in performance section of Firebase. It says "28% of requests took over 2.00 s in the last 2 days."